# Business Day dates sequence in R

Tags: r, pandas

I want to generate dates within a given range in R that are business days according to some calendar. Much like what you can get when you use panda date_range function with frequency 'b' in Python. Does anyone know of R equivalent?

I was hoping there would be something in zoo/xts but couldn't find.

Comment: Do you want to exclude weekends or also country specific public holidays?

Comment: "according to some calender" is fairly wide. You can create a sequence of dates using `seq.Date(to, from, by = "1 day")`, but in order to leave out non-business days you need a way of finding what those days are?

Comment: Exactly, I want to exclude country specific holidays and weekends. If I can specify country calendar with some kind of ISO code then all the better. You can't do that though in panda.date_range.

Comment: See `?is.holiday` in the chron package.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(timeDate)
holidays = holidayNYSE()
daysSeq = as.timeDate(seq(from = as.Date("2016-03-01"), to = as.Date("2016-03-16"), by = "day"))
daysSeq[isBizday(daysSeq, holidays = holidays, wday = 1:5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the `timeDate` package.  It has handy functions like `isBizday` which you can use to check if a vector of dates are business dates based on a specific calendar.

```
isBizday(x, holidays = holidayNYSE(), wday = 1:5)
```

Comment: I installed a packaged called 'biz days' which has 'bizseq' function which seem to be doing what I want except I don't know the default calendar it has stored. Yes, your timeDate function looks more flexible.

Comment: Actually biz days has an option of calendar https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/bizdays.pdf